# This is wrong, but why (and how can I get it to flow better)?

Tags: ruby, hash, optional-parameters

So I am figuring out how to set up some options for a class. 'options' is a hash. I want to

1) filter out options I don't want or need

2) set some instance variables to use elsewhere

3) and set up another hash with the processed options as @current_options.

```
def initialize_options(options)
  @whitelisted_options, @current_options  = [:timestamps_offset, :destructive, :minimal_author], {}
  n_options = options.select { |k,v| @whitelisted_options.include?(k) }
  @current_options[:timestamps_offset] = @timestamp_offset = n_options.fetch(:timestamps_offset, 0)*(60*60*24)
  @current_options[:destructive] = @destructive = n_options.fetch(:destructive, false)
  @current_options[:minimal_author] = @minimal_author = n_options.fetch(:minimal_author, false)
end
```

I'm guessing this is a bit much, no matter what I pass in I get:

```
{:timestamps_offset=>0, :destructive=>false, :minimal_author=>false}
```

When I do this line by line from the command line, it works as I want it to but not in my class. So what is going on and how do I clean this up?

EDIT: this actually works disembodied from the class I'm using it in, but inside it doesn't so the reality is something is going on I'm not aware of right now.

attr_reader :current_options is how this is set on the class, perhaps that needs some revision.

EDIT2: line 2 of the method is supposed to select from @whitelisted_options

EDIT3: Actually turned out to be something I wasn't thinking of..."options" comes in parsed from a yaml file as strings....and I was fetching symbols, changing that around makes a difference where before the method was looking for symbols and finding none, e.g. "destructive" vs :destructive, so always defaulting to the defaults. In short, I just needed to symbolize the hash keys when options are imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Your `@current_options` is initialized as an empty hash. When you filter the `options` passed as params, none of the keys will be present in `@current_options` so `n_options` will end up empty.</strike>

Then when you set up `@current_options` in the following lines, it will always grab the default values `(0, false, false)`, and that's why your output's always the same.

You solve this problem by conditionally initializing @current_options so that it's only set to `{}` once:

@current_options ||= {}

**Post-OP edit:**

Your issue's with `options.select` -- in Ruby 1.8, it doesn't return a Hash, but rather an Array. Your calls to `fetch` are then always failing (as symbols can't be array indexes), so always returning defaults.

Instead, try:

```
n_options = options.inject({}) {|h, p| h[p[0]] = p[1] if @whitelisted_options.include? p[0]; h }
```

where `p` is an array containing each key/value pair.

In Ruby 1.9.2, `Hash.select` behaves the way you expected it to.

**Edit 2: Here's how I'd approach it:**

```
class Foo
  @@whitelisted_options= {:timestamps_offset => 0, :destructive => false, :minimal_author =>false}

  @@whitelisted_options.keys.each do |option|
    define_method(option) { return @current_options[option] rescue nil}
  end

  def initialize_options(options)
    @current_options = {}
    @@whitelisted_options.each {|k, v| @current_options[k] = options[k] || v}
    @current_options
  end
end
```

In use:

```
f = Foo.new
f.destructive #=> nil
f.initialize_options(:minimal_author => true, :ignore => :lol)
f.destructive #=> false
f.minimal_author #=> true
f.timestamps_offset #=> 0
```

Comment: I did change that, but did not reflect that originally. n_options is options with invalid options dropped.

Comment: This is close, but doesn't actually return the set variables, i.e. always returns the defaults options (or I'm not seeing it right yet). But it is close and gives me another clue on doing things slightly different.

Comment: @blueblank My code was returning the `@whitelisted_options` after it set `@current_options`. Fixed :)

Comment: I see it now, I was originally caught up trying to decipher class variables and what you did with .keys.each, but got it.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is `@whitelisted_options` for?
2. What do you want to happen if `:destructive` is not a key in `options`? Do you want to have `:destructive => false`, or do you want `@current_options` to not mention `:destructive` at all?

Comment: @whitelisted is just a list of options available to the class; basically accept only these options and drop all others, if others would happen to passed inadvertently.

Comment: @destructive should default to false

Comment: @blueblank: Why is `@whitelisted` an instance variable rather than a local variable?

Comment: I use it elsewhere to return a list of valid options e.g.thisclass.valid_options => @whitelisted_options.join(",")